# How to stop the content from overlapping the header?

Tags: html, css

Umm...hi!

I'm new here and am a self-taught amateur (read:google-searching-experiment-dude).

I created a fairly basic webpage but when I scroll down, the content overlaps the header. I don't really know how to explain this,so I'll link everything:

https://youtu.be/R05oISKKaXE

Oh, another thing:I'm sure I have a lot of redundant stuff.
Thanks.

Comment: can you post some code please?

Comment: It would be more helpful added to your question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to change the z-index of your elements to make them display on top of each other in a defined order.

Considering a piece of HTML that looks like this,

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

You can set the z-index of each element like so:

```
#header {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
}
#content {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to stackoverflow!

When posting questions related to html/css/javascript you can use a tool like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to create a demo of the problem and post it here, so it is easier for others to help you!

You could try removing the relative position in your .body class and the fixed position on your .header class, that alone might solve your problem.

Comment: Oh~ ok, I see. Thanks!